# Snowflake AWS Privatelink - Python Connector Error Max retries exceeded with url: /session/v1/login-request?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

we recently configured aws privatelink to snowflake account and updated python connector (v.1.8.0) properties to use privatelink URL.

Connection keeps failing with below error.

> Failed to execute request: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='testaccount.us-west-2.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/v1/login-request?warehouse=TEST_WH&request_id=12345&request_guid=f5467 (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",)))

Has anyone encountered this issue when using AWS privatelink?

Any inputs would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you already tried: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/HowTo-Troubleshoot-Privatelink-configuration-for-Snowflake and checked the configurations here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-privatelink.html#sample-configuration-template-for-a-snowflake-account-in-aws-us-east-1 ?

Comment: This will be my futile attempt at trying to list some of the troubleshooting steps to help identify the issue. - https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/HowTo-Troubleshoot-Privatelink-configuration-for-Snowflake - What version of python are you using for the connection? - Are you using AWS lambda in the query? recent git issue opened in the python connector github take a look, is it related?: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues - If we cannot figure it out here, highly recommend collecting more detailed with logs https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-g

Answer (score 0):

On the host where you are running python, if linux or OSX, can you run:

curl -v -L https://testaccount.us-west-2.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com:443

Do you know if you have a proxy in place allowing your Web URL to work?

https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-set-proxy-server-all-major-internet-browsers-windows

That error is because the python code is unable to reach the privatelink URL.  Either it's on a host that is blocked, there is a firewall blocking, or you require a proxy.